# Dynamically create winform controls based on a service call

Tags: c#, winforms

I initially have a radiobutton with multiple options. On a selection, I call a webservice which gives me a list of questions and the type of component to create (radio button, text box, drop-down, etc) for each question. So, how do I create the .net winform controls dynamically based on the service response?

Sample service response:

```
{
 question: 'Did you verify your account?',
 Control: 'Radio Button',
 Options: { 'Yes','No'}
}
```

Comment: Please show us your effort first, then we can try to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the form .cs file do

```
this.Controls.Add(//Control you want to add);
```

You will have to initialize them manually though (or put them hidden somehow).

Other solution is making them invisible and make visible true/false for each one based on the call response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example how you can add controls programmatically. And then you just need parse web service and based on data add controls

```
        Label qs_label = new Label();
        qs_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular);
        qs_label.Size = new Size(150, 18);
        qs_label.Text = item.ToString();
        this.selectionPanel.Controls.Add(qs_label);

        Label m_label = new Label();
        m_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular);
        m_label.Size = new Size(150, 18);
        m_label.Text = "Maturity standard";
        this.selectionPanel.Controls.Add(m_label);

        Label c_label = new Label();
        c_label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular);
        c_label.Size = new Size(170, 18);
        c_label.Text = "Compliance standard";
        this.selectionPanel.Controls.Add(c_label);

        ComboBox m_input = new ComboBox();
        m_input.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular);
        m_input.Size = new Size(200, 22);
        m_input.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.selectionPanel.Controls.Add(m_input);

        ComboBox c_input = new ComboBox();
        c_input.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular);
        c_input.Size = new Size(200, 22);
        c_input.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.selectionPanel.Controls.Add(c_input);
```